# Symfony: select the Asset package based on the extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following assets config:

```
assets:
    json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/build/manifest.json'
    packages:
        s3:
            base_url: https://s3/bucket/
```

and to generate the URL for an image I have to pass the package name to the asset helper every time like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('image.jpg','s3') }}"/>
```

I was wondering whether is's possible to to automatically determine the package based on the file extension. So the Asset component would use s3 automatically for images and the local server for everything else.

Comment: you can create twig extension function named asset_image that you inject package and use it and in twig 
<img src="{{ asset_image('image.jpg') }}"/>

Comment: @T.Abdelmalek it's basically the same. Instead the package name I end up adding the "_image" suffix. Ideally it should be something in the config, similar to the webpack's test thing: "test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,"